# FireFox version of Safari "text only"?

Tags: safari, firefox

I find the "text only" option in Safari - you know, those lines to the left of the URL bar - extremely useful on my iPhone and iPad. However on my Windows laptop for work, I use FireFox and would really, really like that feature. I know I could use third-party apps like Pocket and the like but frankly I would like something "built-in" which doesn't require bloatware.

On a side-note, does this feature have a particular name?

Comment: It's called Reading List

Comment: @Robuust Isn't reading list the feature of "collecting articles" for later use rather than the feature of "transforming webpages to text only"? I don't want to store anything.

Comment: Are you talking about the Reader ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Is that the thing which I am referring to? So... open webpage (usually an article), click "icon with four lines" on the left-hand side of the URL bar, webpage is turned into text only (text size dictated by OS text size setting). I would argue that it is related to Apple software so entirely relevant.

Comment: Yes. that's the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has no built-in reader feature. But you can install an extension to add this feature : [Reader for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/reader/)